# How to give controller a name in a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, directive

I have a directive defined this way:

```
angular
    .module('ui-abc', [ 'xyz'])
    .directive('computer', compute);

function compute( item) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        templateUrl: '../elements/src/template.html',
        scope:{ qwerty : '=',}    
        controller: ['$scope','$sce',  {   
.........
```

}

The controller does not have a name, how can i add one ? I need this name so that I can refer to that controller inside my ui-router configuration. I tried to do this

```
function compute( item) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        templateUrl: '../elements/src/template.html',

        controller: "controllerName"
}

app.controller("controllerName", function(){......
....
```

App is not defined in this module, it is defined in the main app.js controller file.

So, it does not work, what do I have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

here, you **`app`** will be - `var app = angular.module('ui-abc', [ 'xyz']);`
And don't use `controller: "something"`, if you don't have one. It'll be fine if you *just skip that line*.

Comment: thanks but the point of my question is that I do need a controller's name for this module in order to refer to this controller inside my ui-router config file..

Comment: The way I know is - You can set `ng-controller="someController"` in your `template.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the param called 'controllerAs' as below:

```
function compute( item) {
   return {
    restrict: "EA",
    templateUrl: '../elements/src/template.html',

    controller: "controllerName",
    controllerAs: 'cName'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your directive you can put a parameter called controllerAs

directive.js

```
function compute( item) { return {
  restrict: "EA",
  templateUrl: '../elements/src/template.html',
  controller: 'controllerName',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};}
```

you can now call the controller as vm in your template.html

template.html

```
<body><h1>{{ vm.variableName }}</h1></body>
```